About the Serre's proof of the fact $L(1,\chi)\neq 0, \forall \chi\neq\chi_0$
In A Course in Arithmetic, by Serre, he proves the above fact. At the proof, he says "It follows that $\zeta_m$ has all its coefficients greater than those of the series $$\sum_{(n,m)=1} n^{-\phi(m)},$$ which diverges for $s=1/\phi(m)$".
But he obtained this result doing calculations from $\zeta_m$ for $Re(s)>1,$ because only there we have the product form $$\zeta_m(s)=\prod_{p\nmid m} (1-p^{-f(p)s})^{-g(p)}.$$ We even don't know the coefficients of $\zeta_m(s)$ for $Re(s)\leq 1.$
My questions are: how can I conclude the inequality does hold at $Re(s)\leq 1$ and why does an entire analysis of a series in $Re(s)>1$ explain something in $Re(s)\leq 1$?

Did you read the entire proof? Serre directly references the theorems he is using. Specifically, in the context of the argument Serre has built up to an argument that assumes $\zeta_m(s)$ as a (holomorphic) function extends to $re(s) > 0$. Then a theorem on Dirichlet series with positive coefficients forces the actual series representation to extend. And that is the issue because the coefficients force divergence at $s = 1$.
